# File contaning ÿ symbol while saving text file as binary data

Tags: java

I am saving .txt file as a binary format.But at the last line of a binary file,one more character is saved i.e  ÿ

Why this has happened ?
My code is like this :

```
FileOutputStream fout = null;
InputStream fin;
String path="something";
int i = 0;
fout = new FileOutputStream(path);
do {
  i=fin.read();
  fout.write(i);
} while(i != -1);
fout.flush();
fout.close();
```

Comment: "I am saving .txt file as a binary format." - What do you even mean by that? You need to be *much* more specific, and also provide code. Your question is unanswerable at the moment. (I see you've now provided a single line of code. Hopefully more is coming...)

Comment: What character encoding are you using? ANSI or UTF or something else?

Comment: If your file contains a `ÿ` it's because that is what you wrote even if you don't realise this is what your code is doing.

Comment: Please show your complete code, not just the one line that you posted - that one line doesn't help to find out what the problem is.

Comment: That code will throw `NullPointerException`. When someone on `SO` say `complete code`. That means the relevant part of your code, that is having the problem that you have stated, and you haven't stated a `NullPointerException` right?

Comment: files are saving sucessfully...not any NPE

Comment: Where is your `fin.read` reading the input from? In your current code, it is just `null`, and hence `NPE`. Show the initialization code for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty obvious: The ÿ character (unicode U+00FF) you are seeing is the -1 you are writing just before quitting the loop. You should not use `do ... while()` here, instead use the more common idiom:

```
    while ((i = fin.read()) != -1)
        fout.write(i);
```

Comment: Maybe you should start accepting some answers to your questions. Just a hint.